# Request for Explanation in case of Replacement not working

Tags: list-manipulation

The 2 code snippets work on a matrix ABg with 22 rows and two columns containing Strings. Some entries in column 2 are List { } to be recognized by the first Character "{". In the list some items must be changed via Replace[].

I do not understand why the first code is not working (no warnings), whereas the second code is working correctly. What is wrong with the first one?

First code:

```
Do[ If[ABg[[i, 2]] // Characters // First == "{",
ABg[[i, 2]] = (  StringReplace[ABg[[i, 2]],
 {WordBoundary ~~ "5" ~~ WordBoundary -> "15A",
  WordBoundary ~~ "15" ~~ WordBoundary -> "15B"} ] ) ], {i,1,22}]
```

Second code:

```
Do[a = ABg[[i, 2]] // Characters // First;
If[a == "{", ABg[[i, 2]] = (StringReplace[ABg[[i, 2]],
 {WordBoundary ~~ "5" ~~ WordBoundary -> "15A",
  WordBoundary ~~ "15" ~~ WordBoundary -> "15B"} ]) ,], {i,1,22}]
```

Can someone perhaps explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the order of evaluation when you use //. Your expression

```
ABg[[i, 2]] // Characters // First == "{"
```

evaluates as

```
ABg[[i, 2]] // Characters // (First == "{")
```

as can be seen by repeated clicking in the expression (or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> for *expand selection*). What you wanted to do is

```
(ABg[[i, 2]] // Characters // First) == "{"
```

which is what you do in your second code, the assignment has higher priority.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen it, but can you nevertheless still indicate a relevant place in the documentation. I Always think that evaluation goes from outside to inside. (ie. from right to left).

Comment: @Rombert The problem with using infix and postfix notations is that the order of evaluation is not immediately clear. For example a+b c could in principle be computed in two different ways: first a+b, then multiply by c, or first b c, then add a. (Yes, I know the convention, but that convention does not follow from the notation!). The best way of finding the order of evaluation of an expression that uses infix and postfix is to ask for the FullForm of it, so in your case, inspect FullForm[ABg[[i, 2]] // Characters // First == "{"]

Comment: @halirutan Thanks for editing. I did not know about Ctrl+.. I learn a lot on StackExchange.

Comment: @FredSimons No problem.